# .htaccess redirect with host or ip address

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have 2 different domains on the same server:
domain1.com and domain2.com on server address 100.12.12.222
and simple redirection rule for non-www to www

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and I'd like to have a rule like: if host=domain1.com then redirect to www.domain1.com 
and if host=100.12.12.222 don't redirect to www.domain1.com

I tried to add:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^100\.12\.12\.222
RewriteRule (.*) http://100.12.12.222/$1 [R=301,L]
```

which works if the second domain doesn't have non-www to www redirection

so I googled and read apache advices and tried to combine something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^100\.12\.12\.222
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

here I tried to use HTTP_HOST and various things, but it doesn't redirect right.
Your help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the [or] flag.  You want to redirect to www. if the host is not `www...` **and** the remote != 100.12.12.222

Comment: Thank you for your help - in fact I had to change 'REMOTE_ADDR' to HTTP_HOST and remove 'OR' :)